# Primeng Table row selection highlight only for the visible scroll part

Tags: angular, scrollbar, primeng

I have used PrimeNg Table and applied scroll with `scrollDirection="both"` but the issue is, it show the row selection for the visible part of the scroll and once I scroll to right, I can see the highlighted part as below:

Code:

```
<p-table [value]="CommonData" [first]="0" [rows]="pageSize" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3"
[rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]" [columns]="selectedColumns" selectionMode="single" [lazy]="true"
(onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)" [reorderableColumns]="true" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [responsive]="true" paginatorDropdownAppendTo="body" (onPage)="pageIndexChange($event)"
[scrollable]="true" scrollDirection="both">
```

[image]

Not sure, what could be the reason for this..

Answer (score 1):

From PrimeNG documentation : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table

> Set scrollDirection to "both" and give fixed widths to columns to scroll both ways.

You need to set fixed widths for columns for the scroll to function properly. for example :

```
<p-table [value]="customers" [scrollable]="true" scrollDirection="both">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th style="width:100px">Id</th>
            <th style="width:200px">Name</th>
            <th style="width:200px">Country</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-customer>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px">{{customer.id}}</td>
            <td style="width:200px">{{customer.name}}</td>
            <td style="width:200px">{{customer.country.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: I have already added fixed width for th and td and scroll is also there.. but the issue is different..